# postfix: add missing subject header

Tags: postfix

I want postfix to add a Mail-Subject to messages, which do not have a subject already.

Some of my applications are trying to send E-Mail messages which do not contain a subject and these applications cannot be changed by me.
I want that these E-Mail messages get a default-subject, e.g. "mail from App1".

I have tried using postfix' header_checks feature (https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html), but as far as I understand, I can only do these things:

- add a subject to all E-Mail messages (even those which already have a subject):
  `/Message-ID:.*/ PREPEND Subject: I am an extra subject, which is added to all E-Mails, even those that already have a subject`
- change the subject of E-Mail messages, which already have a subject:
  `/Subject:.*/ REPLACE Subject: I am a new subject for all E-Mails which already have a subject`

I think that header_checks might not be the solution I am looking for (as I cannot ask it for "if no subject header exist"). Is there another mechanism that would solve my issue or maybe I am missing something about header_checks that would work for me.

I have also seen the `always_add_missing_headers` option (https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_add_missing_headers), but according to the documentation it does not add the subject header.

Comment: Would it be possible to configure those broken applications to use a dedicated mail server (or a different Postfix instance utilising a different port on your existing mail server) ? Then you don't have to be selective in which messages and/or subjects to modify/add/overwrite ... - Because the alternative approach I though of, with alterMIME, also has the limitation that is there is no "add header when absent"  function, only `-alter-header=\"...\" --alter-with=\"...\" --alter-mode=<prefix|suffix|replace>`

Comment: Yes, I think it would be possible to run a separate postfix instance for those applications. I do not particularly like it though as it seems to be quite a complex setup in the end.

thanks for thinking about a solution with alterMIME and even more thanks for mentioning that alterMIME would have similar problems as check_headers